# Spring Mongo Template error while creating bean

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-mongo

I am using two databases so I added both in My context servlet. But it gives error..
My servlet.context is

```
<!-- Mongo settings -->
    <mongo:mongo id="mongo" host="192.148.5.5" port="27017" />

    <beans:bean id="mongoTemplate"
        class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="mongo" />
        <beans:constructor-arg name="databaseName"
            value="WriteDB" />

    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="mongoTemplate2"
        class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="mongo" />
        <beans:constructor-arg name="databaseName"
            value="readDB" />

    </beans:bean>
    <mongo:repositories base-package="com.cheasyy.cofinding,com.cheasyy.cofinding.controller" />
```

Error is

Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate com.cheasyy.cofinding.service.profile.ProfileServiceImpl.mt; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: [mongoTemplate, mongoTemplate2]
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
Where I am missing?

My ProfileServiceImpl class is
@Service

```
public class ProfileServiceImpl implements profileService {

    @Autowired
    MongoTemplate mt;
    @Override
    public void insert(Profile profile) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("in service ipl");
    mt.save(profile);   
    System.out.println("saved in db");

    }

}
```

Comment: Have you read the message? How could Spring autowire a MongoTemplate in ProfileServiceImpl if there are two MongoTemplates defined and you don't tell Spring which one you want to autowire? Where's the code of ProfileServiceImpl?

Comment: I edited the code with ProfileServiceImpl class.

Comment: Looks like the same issue here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20536791/spring-adding-multiple-gridfs-templates-in-servlet-context-xml/20545329#20545329

Answer (score 0):

Straight from [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers):

> 5.9.3 Fine-tuning annotation-based autowiring with qualifiers
>
> Because autowiring by type may lead to multiple candidates, it is often necessary to have more control over the selection process. One way to accomplish this is with Spring's @Qualifier annotation.

Click the link for more details.